# Quill for blazor with @bind-Value=@

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly, quill

There are several ready made projects available, also couple of NuGet packages to download. I have found good option in NuGet library. However it is missing some customization in JavaScript interop. How I can take sources from NuGet package to use them independently in my project or as an option how to get it working without any NuGet?

So I have created

**QuillEditor.razor:**

```
@inherits InputTextArea
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime

<textarea value="@Value"></textarea>
```

**QuillEditor.razor.cs:**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using Microsoft.JSInterop;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BlazingDiary.Client.Shared.Components
{
  public class QuillEditorBase : ComponentBase
  {
    public string Id
    {
      get;
    }

    [Parameter]
    public string Value
    {
      get;
      set;
    }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<string> ValueChanged
    {
      get;
      set;
    }

    [Parameter(CaptureUnmatchedValues = true)]
    public Dictionary<string, object> ElementAttributes
    {
      get;
      set;
    }

    [Inject]
    public IJSRuntime Runtime
    {
      get;
      set;
    }

    public QuillEditorBase()
    {
      Id = $"quill_{Guid.NewGuid()}";
    }

    [JSInvokable("quill-onchange")]
    public async void OnChange(string value)
    {
      Value = value;
      await ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(value);
    }

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
      if (firstRender)
      {
        await Runtime.InvokeVoidAsync("blazor.quill.initialize", Id, Value, DotNetObjectReference.Create(this));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**quill.js:**

```
window.blazor = {};
window.blazor.quill = {
    initialize: function (id, value, dotnet) {

        var dataOptions = JSON.parse(document.getElementById(id).getAttribute("data-options"));
        var defaultOptions = {
            modules: {
                toolbar: [
                    [{ header: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, false] }],
                    ["bold", "italic", "underline", "strike"],
                    [{ 'list': "ordered" }, { 'list': "bullet" }, { 'indent': "-1" }, { 'indent': "+1" }],
                    ["link", "image", "blockquote"]
                ]
            },
            theme: "snow"
        };

        var options = Object.assign({}, defaultOptions, dataOptions);
        var quill = new Quill(`#${id}`, options);

        quill.on("text-change", function (delta) {
            dotnet.invokeMethodAsync("quill-onchange", quill.container.firstChild.innerHTML);
        });

        quill.container.firstChild.innerHTML = value;
    }
};
```

Above code is not working as I am not sure how to tie all together.

Basically I would like to understand how this has been done, but as original GitHub project seems to be deleted, I don't understand how it has been done? Can somebody drop some light?
https://www.nuget.org/packages/BlazorQuill/

Comment: What functionality does this Nuget package you use achieve? You can describe and maybe find an alternative package.

Comment: @Chaodeng I want to add more tools into toolbar in quill.js

Comment: In the toolbar (in js) you can add any items, if you want to add items by code, you can add new parameter to initialize function, then use them on tools option. (json data)

Comment: You should read the docs on JSInterop... They are well made and cover everything... almost...

Comment: `QuildEditorBase` is indeed initializing the Id, but I don't see you passing the Id to the `js` function. That's what's missing.